# Error 'is not in list'

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get the index values of the values in outputx[vX]

```
>>> outs = np.array(outputx[vX]).tolist()
>>> print outs
[0.806, 0.760, 0.8]
>>> print type(outs)
(type 'list')
>>> idx = outputX.index(outs)
error -> [0.806, 0.760, 0.8] is not in list
```

What does this mean, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: try `outputX.index(0)` or `outputX.index(1)`. Or `outputX.index(outputX.find(0.8))`

Comment: What type is `outputX`?  Also, your code references `outputX` and `outputx` -- Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

The `index` list method expects a single value, and returns that value's position in the list on which the method is called. If the given value isn't in the list the method will raise a `ValueError` exception. So, for example:

```
>>> [2, 4, 6, 8].index(6)
2
>>> [2, 4, 6, 8].index("no such value")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'no such value' is not in list
```

The error occurs in your code because there is no element in `outputX` (should that be `outputx`, by the way Python is case-sensitive) containing the list `[0.806, 0.760, 0.8]`.

The reason for this is that you are comparing data of different types. It isn't entriely clear from the question what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of indices you might use list comprehensions:

```
idx = [outputX.index(i) for i in outs]
```

But you should be dead sure that all values of the `outs` list are in the `outputX` list also, otherwise python will throw you a `ValueError`.